# Get relative path in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Given an arbitrary path `path` and some other path `base` to a directory, how can I get a new relative path from `base` to the same object in file system as `path`?

For example `(relpath #p"~/foo" #p"~/bar/")` must give me `#p"../foo"`. There is such a function in Julia, for example, which is also called `relpath`. Is there anything like that in Common Lisp (either in the standard or as a third-party library)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest to what you are looking for is called [`enough-namestring`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_namest.htm):

```lisp
(enough-namestring "~/foo/bar/baz" "~/foo/")
==> "bar/baz"
```

Comment: This, unfortunately, does not work in this case: `(enough-namestring "~/foo/" "~/bar/")` returning `"~/foo/"`. I'll accept this answer anyway for simplicity and because I was not aware of `enough-namestring` earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If both paths exists, you can normalize them to an absolute pathname by calling `truename`; then, since pathname directories are lists, you can easily find the longest common path and build a relative pathname with as many `:up` elements as necessary to go from the second pathname to the first:

```
(defun rp (p1 p2)
  (loop
     for d1 on (pathname-directory (truename p1))
     for d2 on (pathname-directory (truename p2))
     while (string= (first d1) (first d2))
     finally
       (return
         (make-pathname
          :directory (append (list :relative)
                     (substitute :up t d2 :test (constantly t))
                     d1)
          :defaults p1))))
```

For example, assuming "/tmp/foo" exists and "~" is "/home/user/":

```
> (rp "/tmp/foo" "~/")
#P"../../tmp/foo"
```

This should cover a lot of common use cases, but this has its limitations (no wildcard names, files must exist, and probably other corner cases)

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is related to common lisp but as a hint there is a solution within emacs lisp. The emacs lisp function to return the relative path is [file-relative-name](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Relative-File-Names.html).